# Foreign key created in shadow and appending random 1 to column name - ASP:NET EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

When I migrate my new models and data I get the following error for multiple foreign keys:

> The foreign key property 'InsurancePolicy.InsuranceSubjectID1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'InsuranceSubjectID' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.

The weird thing is that I define my relationships the same throughout all models, but some work okay (FK without 1 is stored) and some don't.

Example of my models:

```
public class InsurancePolicy
{
    public int InsurancePolicyID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal FinalSum { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public int? InsuredID { get; set; }
    public Insured? Insured { get; set; }
    public int? InsuranceSubjectID;
    public InsuranceSubject? InsuranceSubject { get; set; }
    public int? InsuranceSubtypeID;
    public InsuranceSubtype? InsuranceSubtype { get; set; }
}

public class InsuranceSubject
{
    public int InsuranceSubjectID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal EstimatedValue { get; set; }
    public int? InsuredID;
    public Insured? Insured;
    public int? InsuranceSubjectTypeID { get; set; }
    public InsuranceSubjectType? InsuranceSubjectType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InsurancePolicy>? InsurancePolicies { get; set; }
}
```

I tried my code without the foreign key properties and only left the reference navigation property (deleted the int and left the object) and it worked okay, but I need FK ints for future implementation.

Here is GitHub repo link for more insight (branch model-extension): https://github.com/lenartgolob/Insurance-IS/tree/model-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `public virtual` in front of my reference navigation properties and it solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding public virtual does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 17):

Ok.. For me.

I had Parent/Child relationship.

And I had put in the scalar's (on the **child**) that also included  the parent FK (as int), and had defined the orm mapping (again, on the child) for the (same) scalar FK "int".

```
public class MyParent
{
    public int MyParentKey { get; set; }


    public ICollection<MyChild> MyKids { get; set; }

}


public class MyChild
{
    public int MyChildKey { get; set; }

    public int MyParentKey { get; set; } /* FK Scalar */

    public MyParent TheMyParent { get; set; }

}
```

I had Orm-Mapped the MyParentKey the SCALAR (in this case an "int") on the MyChildOrmMap.

But **I had NOT orm-mapped** the OBJECT (in this case the "MyParent" object).. via the property that pointed to that object (in this case the "TheMyParent" property).

Once I coded the 1:N relationship for the OBJECT (in this case the 'TheMyParent') (and the reciprocal MyKids), the error went away.

Aka, I was missing the below "HasOne/WithMany" orm-mapping (the below code would be in the MyChildMap (the fluent orm map)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

        builder.HasOne<MyParent>(me => me.TheMyParent)
            .WithMany(parent => parent.MyKids)
            .HasForeignKey(me => me.MyParentKey)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_MyChild_To_MyParent_MyParentKey");
```

Comment: Right. if it is a one to one relationship, you can use the generic `HasForeignKey`, i.e. `HasForeignKey<Entity>(o => o.KeyProperty)`

Answer (score 3):

For me, my mistack was not give the `WithOne` relation letting the EF try to create the relation for his self, like this:

```cs
            modelBuilder.Entity<Catalog>(builder =>
            {
                builder.ToTable("Catalogs");
                builder
                    .HasMany(catalog => catalog.Products)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(product => product.CatalogId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
```

And when i changed for this syntax the migration executed with success and without duplicated property:

```cs
            modelBuilder.Entity<Catalog>(builder =>
            {
                builder.ToTable("Catalogs");
                builder
                    .HasMany(catalog => catalog.Products)
                    .WithOne(product => product.Catalog)
                    .HasForeignKey(product => product.CatalogId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the type of property ID in the FK part differed from the one in PK entity part:

```
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid payment id")]
    public int PaymentId { get; set; } // NOTICE INT HERE SHOULD BE LONG

    public virtual Payment Payment { get; set; }
```

where Payment had long property for ID:

```
public class Payment {
 public long Id {get;set;}
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me was that I mistakenly referred the same entity twice:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategoryProduct>()
            .HasKey(tl => new {tl.ProductCategoryId, tl.ProductId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategoryProduct>()
            .HasOne(t => t.ProductCategory)
            .WithMany(t => t.ProductCategoryProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProductCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategoryProduct>()
            .HasOne(p => p.ProductCategory) // this should be Product
            .WithMany(p => p.ProductCategoryProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: I see. I was doing the same thing, defining in propert as `Object Object` and also adding on the builder with `HasOne<Object>`. Thanks! Your answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error could occur if the `HasOne` method is used without providing a lambda expression that defines the relationship between entities.
Try using

```
builder.HasOne<MyParent>(me => me.TheMyParent);
```

instead of

```
builder.HasOne<MyParent>()
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it was repetition of key.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PokemonCategory>()
            .HasKey(pc => new { pc.pokemonId, pc.categoryId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<PokemonCategory>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Pokemon)
            .WithMany(pc => pc.PokemonCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.pokemonId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PokemonCategory>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Pokemon)       //it should be p.Category
            .WithMany(pc => pc.pokemonCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.categoryId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that there are three options. The property:

1. is either not mapped,
2. is already used for another relationship, or
3. is incompatible with the associated primary key type

Here the problem is the third one: your PK InsuranceSubjectID is of type **int**, but you are trying to map it to FK, that is **int?**. Make the FK not nullable and it should work as expected.